# Symfony 2. Delete entity on click

Tags: symfony, onclick, entity

I need to delete row from database on click. I got database with emails. 
And I need to generate button near each input with e-mail from database and on click action to delete it.

```
{% for inc in Incmejl %}
                        <input type="text" value="{{ inc.getEmail()  }}" >
                    {% endfor %}
```

Entity name: Reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So each email has an id in DB, so what you want to do is create a button which calls a route with this parameter id :

for instance, in the view

```
 <a href="{{ path('my_delete_route', { 'id': email.id } }}">delete</a>
```

this route my_delete_route will call the controller DeleteAction($id) which will look like

```
 $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:Entity');
 $email = $repository->find($id); 
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
 $em->remove($email); 
 $em->flush();
```

The route

```
my_delete_route:
    path:     whatever/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeMyBundle:MyController:Delete }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I thing that, this is it:) Thanks a lot\